# Does deleting rows of table increases read time of the table in MYSQL Database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a database with a specific table having over 15 million entries and entries into that table increases at the rate of 1million rows per week, and most of which are unused. Does removing rows (say 10million) reduce the read time of the database?
Note: the table has a unique ID with AUTO INCREMENT(int) column.

Comment: You probably want to partition the table by the date of insert.

Comment: Your question depends on the used storage engine..You might need to reclaim disk space manual with `OPTIMIZE [table]`.. And off cource the queryes that being used.

Comment: @Raymond Nijland The storage engine that is currently being used is Innodb.